# Is there any way in C to know how many processes there are with the same pgid?

Tags: c, linux, process, pid

I want to know if there is any function in C (Linux) to know how many processes are there with a certain pgid.
For example:

```
  PID  PGID  PPID COMMAND
 9024 27852 27855 ./asdf
 9033 27852 27856 ./asdf
 9035 27852 27854 ./asdf
 9037 27852 27856 ./asdf
 9039 27852 27854 ./asdf
```

If I have these processes, the function(27852) will return 5 processes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Succinctly, No — AFAICT.

POSIX provides a number of functions for manipulating process groups, but not an interrogation function to find out which processes belong to a specified process group.  This is consistent with other system calls; there are no system calls that return fully open-ended lists of 'items of interest'.

- [`getpgid()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getpgid.html)
- [`setpgid()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setpgid.html)
- [`getpgrp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getpgrp.html)
- [`setpgrp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setpgrp.html)
- [`killpg()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/killpg.html)
- [`posix_spawnattr_getpgroup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/posix_spawnattr_getpgroup.html)
- [`posix_spawnattr_setpgroup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/posix_spawnattr_setpgroup.html)
- [`tcgetpgrp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/tcgetpgrp.html)
- [`tcsetpgrp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/tcsetpgrp.html)

You can search through the Linux manual pages at http://man7.org/linux/man-pages:

- Section 2 (system calls): http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/
- Section 3 (library functions): http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/

The same names as in POSIX turn up; no other relevant looking entries turn up.